# I'm trying to find a CRM with some specific features

Tags: crm

I already looked at a few including Zoho, Salesforce, Sugar, and Epesi. Each one of those was either to expensive or was lacking what we needed.

I'm hoping someone out there knows of a CRM that:

- Is web based
- Has a module for opportunities/sales (they want to be able to record payments and link them to customers)
- Has the ability for customizing fields (deleting standard fields & adding new ones), as well as formula based custom fields
- Ability to import data from a CSV file and export data as well
- Ability to run customized reports
- Has a module for customer accounts
- Workflow automation. Specifically, they want there to be a field which sets when the customer is due to be billed and have that update every month when the billing date passes. So for example, if the billing date is January 20th once January 20th passes the field should automatically update to February 20th and so on and this should be the process for all customers stored in the system.

Preferably something open source so I can modify the code as needed. My client would be willing to pay a monthly price of up to $30 a month. A one-time upfront cost would be even better.

Answer (score 2):

WORKetc is a web based business management application that combines features of CRM, PM, and billing into system. It integrates these aspects directly so that certain items can be attached to one another, I.E. contacts and projects, timesheets and projects, to-dos and leads, you get the idea.

It's centered around its CRM features, which include opportunity/sale tracking, and these can be integrated with the invoicing/quoting module and also attached to products from the product catalog, and once established as a sale can be turned into subscription sales that bill automatically on a monthly rate.

WORKetc has custom fields, website integration forms, has data import/export in the CSV format, runs business wide reports on hundreds of different forms of data in real time, and has a customer login portal: you can invite an unlimited amount of clients to come in and collaborate on projects, view invoices, follow up on support tickets, etc (based on permissions you set).

Compare with other CRM systems here: http://www.worketc.com/compare

David